# usb headphones don't work in xubuntu

Tags: 14.04, usb, xubuntu, alsa, headphones

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04.02 and my C-Media USB headphones don't "just work."

When I plug them in, entries are created in `/dev/snd`, but nothing appears in sound settings, nor do they appear in the output of `aplay -l`.

Restarting pulseaudio (i.e `pulseaudio -k`, then wait for it to restart) does not help.

If I `chmod a+rw` the headphones' `/dev/snd` entries, everything works.

The USB vendor id is `0d8c`, device id is `000c`.  I'm sure the `chmod` is not the "right" way of solving this problem, but I can't find any other method that works.

Comment: FWIW on Kubuntu 19.04 I have the same vendor MAC ID (SADES usb gaming headset) and all that was needed was to go in to the system sound settings (K-menu > settings > ...) and select the USB device as the default. It was defaulting my HDMIA connection to a screen that doesn't have speakers/mic.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot of posts on this subject I have managed to get usb headphones to work by:

1. Connect your usb headphones to your computer
2. Click on volume controle (thunar / multimedia/ pulse audio volume control
3. On output devices click on headphones and click on green yes button
   next to little locker icon
4. Below, you will see audio controller analog stereo /  click on green  yes button  as above
5. IT WORKS  / at least for me it worked.

If you disconnect your headphones, you must do the same thing again to make them work.